# Proof of the limit of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-writing

The sequence is:

$a_n$ = $\frac 1n$ [$(\frac 1n)^2 + (\frac 2n)^2 + (\frac 3n)^2...(\frac nn)^2$]

The objective is a proof of the limit from 1 to infinity. Just from toying around with a few examples, I speculate the limit is (1/3), but I'm not sure. This is how far I am into the proof (basically just the skeleton).

Let $\epsilon$ > 0. Choose N> *_*. Let n$\in \mathbb{N}$, n>N. We need |$\frac 1n$ [$(\frac 1n)^2 + (\frac 2n)^2 + (\frac 3n)^2...(\frac nn)^2$] - $\frac 13$| < $\epsilon$.

I don't really know how to manipulate this to get something useful. Any advice?

Comment: Riemann sums would be something to look at.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Hint:* $$1^2+2^2+\ldots+n^2 = \dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}.$$

Answer (score 1):

We can write $\displaystyle a_{n}=\frac{1}{n^3}[1^{2}+...+n^{2}]$. Now if you apply the hint given by @njguliyev, it should be immediately clear what needs to be done.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
$$
a_{n} = {1 \over n}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\pars{k \over n}^{2}
=
{1 \over n^{3}}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k^{2}
$$
Now, you can get the sum !!!.

Answer (score 0):

We write $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (\frac {i^{2}}{n^{2}})}{n}.$ Now, let $\frac {1}{n}$ be the distance between two points in the partition and note that the sum is of $\text{sup{f(x)}}$ on every subinterval of $[0,1]$. So, the limit as $n\rightarrow \infty$ is equivalent to $\int_{0}^{1}x^{2}dx$ by the definition of Riemann integrability. This is equivalent to saying the limit is $\frac {1}{3}$.

Answer (score -2):

$$1+4+9+...+n^2=n(n+1)(2n+1)/6$$

so

$$|1/n [(1/n)^2+(2/n)^2+(3/n)^2...(n/n)^2] - 1/3|=
|1/n^3 [(1)^2+(2)^2+(3)^2...(n)^2] - 1/3|$$

$$|1/n^3\cdot(n(n+1)(2n+1)/6) -1/3|=|(n+1)(2n+1)/6n^2 -1/3|=|(2n^2+3n+1-2n^2)/6n^2|$$

Can you go on?